# Meteor Iron Router doesn't call onBeforeAction if data returns null/undefined

Tags: javascript, redirect, meteor, iron-router

I am using Meteor with iron-router and I'm trying to redirect the user back to the login-page if he is no logged in. But on some routes the onBeforeAction is not called. And as I discovered this has something to do with the data which is returned by the data function on the route.
If data returns null/undefined the onBeforeAction is not called and it displays the layout without the data.
If data returns i.e. an empty object it is calling the onBeforeAction and redirecting to the login-page.

1) Is this the right behaviour or is there something wrong with my route definition?

2) Is it possible that the onBeforeAction function is called before the page is rendered? Because it always show the layout/view for a short moment which is not that nice.

So, I have this route:

```
    this.route('dashboardPortfolio', {
        path: ['/dashboard/portfolio'],
        layoutTemplate: 'dashboardLayout',
        yieldTemplates: {
            'header': {to: 'header'},
            'dashboardHeader': {to: 'dashboardHeader'},
            'footerMain' : {to: 'footer'}
        },
        notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
        loadingTemplate: 'dashboardLoading',
        waitOn: function() {
            return Meteor.subscribe("portfolio-edit");
        },
        data: function() {
            var portfolio = Portfolio.findOne({user: Meteor.userId()});
            if(portfolio) return portfolio;
            else return {};
            // return Portfolio.findOne({user: Meteor.userId()});
        }
    });
```

and my onBeforeAction:

```
var OnBeforeActions;

OnBeforeActions = {
    loginRequired: function(route, asd, pause) {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            this.layout('login');
            this.render('login');
        } else {
            this.next();
        }
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(OnBeforeActions.loginRequired, {
    except: ['register', 'login', 'about', 'portfolio']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "except" by "only" in the next line:

```
except: ['register', 'login', 'about', 'portfolio']
```

Good luck!

Comment: That would mean that you have to be logged in to open the login/register page. Blacklist -> whitelist style.